# How can I remove an EventFilter in JavaFX created with a lambda

Tags: lambda, event-handling, javafx-8

I would like to be able to remove an event filter which was set up with a lambda.  I am not sure if this is possible?

I have seen this example using inner classes: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/1120__JavaFX_Event_Filter.htm

However if I create my filter like so:

```
addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
        PaneWithSelectionListener parent = (PaneWithSelectionListener)getParent();
        parent.selectAnnotation(this);
        enableTextEditing(event);
        event.consume();
    });
```

I would like to be able to remove this - can I do this while using lambdas or do I need to use inner classes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store it:

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> myHandler = ...
```

Then add the filter:

```
addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, myHandler);
```

and later on remove it:

```
removeEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, myHandler);
```

Comment: That is how I did it - just wondering if there was a way to do this using Lambdas.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear - would there be a way to remove it without having to hold a reference?  Similar to setOnMousePressed(event -> null) to remove the listener?